# Block an vaulty account and can pc can acces my vaulty account?

Tags: accounts

Can you block a vaulty account? 
My phone had been stolen and the suspect is one of my friends. They know my lock screen pasword and i was worried if they can acces this vault in the computer and open my private files. So i was wondering to block my account inorder to remove those files.

Comment: Can you link to the app you're asking about? There are a lot of "vault" apps all with very similar names, so it's best to be clear which one you mean.

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as i know, if there are decrypted files on a device that were encrypted by that device, you can't access them from a computer -unless you have some very advanced computer knowledge, which i doubt your "friend" will be that desperate. [Here](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-edge/765033-can-usb-port-access-encrypted-sd-card.html) is a link that talks about accessing encrypted data on another device. I know this discussion is about an sd card, but it's still the same idea. You have data in a vault that is encrypted.